# Есть ли в Selenium или Selenide метод для обнуления элемента страницы

Tags: java, selenium, автоматизация, selenide

Я написал следующий метод для очистки поля ввода:

```
/**
 * Очищает поле ввода у элемента
 *
 * @param locator локатора элемента xpath или css
 */
public AbstractPage sendButtonPressesBackSpace(String locator) {
    logger.info(String.format("Очищает поле ввода у элемента {%s}", locator));
    SelenideElement el = getSelenideElement(locator);
    while (el.val().length() != 0)
        el.sendKeys(Keys.BACK_SPACE);
    return this;
}
```

Сделано это из-за того, что Angular обрабатывает только пользовательские действия и `setValue("")` не действует должным образом...

Вопрос такой: Есть ли у Selenium или Selenide методы для обнуления элемента? ибо я найти их не смог

Comment: как вариант можно исполнить скрипт (Selenium) и в нем очистить поле. И по идее должно сработать верно.

Comment: что за скрипт? я жду конкретные примеры кода

Comment: @Tsyklop, так что? вы под скриптом имеете ввиду какие-то функции селениум или метод executejavascript который предполагает код на javascript? 
я ищу функцию которая имитирует события очистки поля ввода, аналогично такой что я написал.
вопрос в том,есть ли такая уже готовая в какой-то библиотеке, или моя функция является актуальной.
ибо как я сказал ранее, Ангуляр может не обработать присвоение пустой строки полю. Код конечно сработает и поле очистится, но после отправки формы, то поле останется заполненым

Comment: Да, имею в виду код JS исполнить. Штука в том что там можно убрать значение и вызвать событие onChange или какое-то другое, которое поможет ангулару понять что значение изменилось.

Comment: @Tsyklop, да я так делаю с простым полями ввода, но не во всех случаях это работает.. поэтому я пришел к методу `sendKeys(Keys.BACK_SPACE)`

Comment: Вот опробуйте. https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/562

Answer (score 1):

Задаем в стринговую переменную значение ввода ctrl+a+delete, а затем передаем его в поле ввода

```
public static String deleteString = Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL, "a") + Keys.DELETE;
el.sendKeys(deleteString);
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]